# Proving that there doesn't exists a complex function satisfying this particular condition

Tags: complex-analysis

This question was part of my assignment which could not be discussed due to pendamic.

> Question : If $f \in  H(U)$ , $f(0)=0$ , $f'(0) \neq 0$ then prove that there is no $g \in H$ $(U/{0})$ such that $g^2 =f$ .

I will not be able to provide anything as attempt as I am unable to have any intution on which result should I use. Kindly try to understand.

Any help will be really appretiated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there is $g \in H(U \setminus \{0\})$ with $g^2=f$ on $U \setminus \{0\}.$

Then $ \lim_{z \to 0}g(z)^2= \lim_{z \to 0}f(z)=f(0)=0.$ Hence $ \lim_{z \to 0}g(z)=0.$

This shows that $g$ has a removable singularity at $0$. For short: $g \in H(U)$ and $g(0)=0.$

We get $2gg'=f'.$ This implies that $f'(0)=0.$ A contradiction.